# how to get full details of each product item in mysql database in prestashop

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i'm trying to get full details of each item(product id, product name, reference code, features, description_short, description) in database but i don't know the exact query for this,
 my database is mysql all the details required for the item is resided in different tables...
each feature name has different id's and each feature value has different id's, i don't know the query for getting all the details for an item..

please send me the query for this....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this query

```
SELECT
        a.`id_product`,b.name as name,`reference`,a.price as price,sa.active as active
        , shp.name as shopname, a.id_shop_default, MAX(image_shop.id_image) id_image, cl.name `name_category`, sa.`price`, 0 AS price_final, sav.`quantity` as sav_quantity, sa.`active`
        FROM `ps_product` a
        LEFT JOIN `ps_product_lang` b ON (b.`id_product` = a.`id_product` AND b.`id_lang` = 1 AND b.`id_shop` = 1)

        LEFT JOIN `ps_image` i ON (i.`id_product` = a.`id_product`)
        LEFT JOIN `ps_stock_available` sav ON (sav.`id_product` = a.`id_product` AND sav.`id_product_attribute` = 0
         AND sav.id_shop = 1 )  JOIN `ps_product_shop` sa ON (a.`id_product` = sa.`id_product` AND sa.id_shop = 1)
                LEFT JOIN `ps_category_lang` cl ON (sa.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category` AND b.`id_lang` = cl.`id_lang` AND cl.id_shop = 1)
                LEFT JOIN `ps_shop` shop ON (shop.id_shop = 1) 
                LEFT JOIN `ps_image_shop` image_shop ON (image_shop.`id_image` = i.`id_image` AND image_shop.`cover` = 1 AND image_shop.id_shop = 1) 

        GROUP BY sa.id_product
```

Answer (score 1):

Mh, you should use this:

```
$product = new Product($product_id, false, $id_lang, $row['id_shop']);
```

Id shop if using multishop.

And after this u can reach all important values: $product->name and etc... Also can get all attributes.

```
Attribute::getAttributes($id_lang, $not_null = false)
```

Comment: thanks for your replay... i want all details in mysql-workbench please tell me the query for this..

Answer (score 1):

SQL for all products (compatible e.g. with WooCommerce CSV import suite) includes taxes in the regular_price

```
SELECT CONCAT('PS', p.id_product) AS 'sku',
    p.active AS 'Active (0/1)',
    pl.name AS 'post_title',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REPLACE(pc.name, ' / ', '>')  SEPARATOR '|') AS 'tax:product_cat',
    p.price AS 'Price tax excl.',
    ROUND(p.price * (COALESCE(ptx.rate, 0) / 100 + 1), 2) AS 'regular_price',
    COALESCE(ptx.rate, 0) AS 'Tax',
    p.wholesale_price AS 'Wholesale price',
    p.on_sale AS 'On sale (0/1)',
    p.reference AS 'Reference #',
    p.supplier_reference AS 'Supplier reference #',
    p.ean13 AS 'EAN13',
    p.upc AS 'UPC',
    p.ecotax AS 'Ecotax',
    p.weight AS 'weight',
    p.quantity AS 'stock',
    "yes" AS 'manage_stock',
    pl.description_short AS 'post_excerpt',
    pl.description AS 'post_content',
    pl.meta_title AS 'Meta-title',
    pl.meta_keywords AS 'Meta-keywords',
    pl.meta_description AS 'Meta-description',
    pl.link_rewrite AS 'URL rewritten',
    pl.available_now AS 'Text when in stock',
    pl.available_later AS 'Text when backorder allowed',
    p.available_for_order AS 'Available for order',
    p.date_add AS 'post_date',
    p.show_price AS 'Show price',
    p.online_only AS 'Available online only',
    p.`condition` AS 'Condition',
    concat( 'http://svartrecords.com/shoppe/img/p/',mid(im.id_image,1,1),'/', if (length(im.id_image)>1,concat(mid(im.id_image,2,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>2,concat(mid(im.id_image,3,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>3,concat(mid(im.id_image,4,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>4,concat(mid(im.id_image,5,1),'/'),''), im.id_image, '.jpg' ) AS 'images'
FROM ps_product p LEFT JOIN
ps_product_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product AND pl.id_lang = 1 JOIN
ps_tax_rule ptxgrp ON ptxgrp.id_tax_rules_group = p.id_tax_rules_group JOIN
ps_tax ptx ON ptx.id_tax = ptxgrp.id_tax  JOIN
ps_image im ON p.id_product = im.id_product JOIN
ps_category_product pcp ON pcp.id_product = p.id_product JOIN
ps_category_lang pc ON pcp.id_category = pc.id_category AND pc.id_lang = 1
WHERE p.active = 1
GROUP BY p.id_product
```

Get images using wget, this seemed a more durable way for me:

```
SELECT CONCAT('wget -O PS', p.id_product, '.jpg ', concat( 'http://svartrecords.com/shoppe/img/p/',mid(im.id_image,1,1),'/', if (length(im.id_image)>1,concat(mid(im.id_image,2,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>2,concat(mid(im.id_image,3,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>3,concat(mid(im.id_image,4,1),'/'),''),if (length(im.id_image)>4,concat(mid(im.id_image,5,1),'/'),''), im.id_image, '.jpg')) AS 'exec'
FROM ps_product p LEFT JOIN
ps_product_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product AND pl.id_lang = 1 JOIN
ps_tax_rule ptxgrp ON ptxgrp.id_tax_rules_group = p.id_tax_rules_group JOIN
ps_tax ptx ON ptx.id_tax = ptxgrp.id_tax  JOIN
ps_image im ON p.id_product = im.id_product JOIN
ps_category_product pcp ON pcp.id_product = p.id_product JOIN
ps_category_lang pc ON pcp.id_category = pc.id_category AND pc.id_lang = 1
WHERE p.active = 1
GROUP BY p.id_product
```